# RSpec fails for no obvious reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

So I'm using `rspec` to test my code as I'm going through the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), and I keep getting this error when I test the code in [listing 3.20](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code%3ahome_view_full_html). Everything checks out when I look at it with my eyeball, but RSpec doesn't seem to like it.

*(Note that I just did one of the pages, not all three because they all give the same error)*

> james@tristan:~/rails_projects/sample_app$
>   rspec
>   spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb
>
> F...
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) PagesController should have the
>   right title
>        Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title",
>          expected following output to contain a  | Home tag:
>          
>        # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in
>   `block (2 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.97999 seconds 4
>   examples, 1 failure
>
> james@tristan:~/rails_projects/sample_app$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of that spec file it says:

```
before(:each) do
  #
  # Define @base_title here.
  #
end
```

Does your spec assign a value to `@base_title`?

Comment: Not to sound like an idiot, but my spec file doesn't have that **or** `@base_title` - there's nothing like that there.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was looking at the wrong one. The spec is in section 3.19?

Comment: That didn't answer it, but it put me in the right direction to fix it. Cheers!